# How do I use conditional statement for different HTML output in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to use different Bootstrap layouts depending on how many images are found. Currently, I can get a list of images stored in Postgres by doing this:

```
{% for image in post.images %}
 <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-1">
       <a href="javascript:void();"><img src="/media/{{ image }}" alt="post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 row m-0 p-0">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <a href="javascript:void();"><img src="images/page-img/p1.jpg" alt="post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100"></a>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
        <a href="javascript:void();"><img src="images/page-img/p1.jpg" alt="post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In my database, I have images listed listed like:

```
{"/user01/post/Annotation 2020-04-04 132805.png","/user01/post/Annotation 2020-04-05 093855.png","/user01/post/Annotation 2020-04-05 100056.png",/user01/post/default.jpg,/user01/post/Django01.png,/user01/post/Django02.png}
```

I wanted to use an if/then/else statement that would return the amount of images and then only use a specified bootstrap class depending on the image count.

post.image.count did not work and I'm wondering how I can get the count of the images.

Comment: Did `post.images.count` work? (with a `s`), otherwise have you tried `len(post.images)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just simply pass post images count to the templates through context like:

```
def get_post(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render('templates/post.html',context={post:post,post_image_count:post.images.count}
```